# Android - CountDownTimer will not use a variable as the first parameter

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to pass the countdowntimer a variable and use that variable as the amount of milliseconds to count down. If I simply enter the value the countdown works properly, but if I pass it a long variable it just runs the onFinish function.

Here's the actual code:

```
public CountDownTimer countDown = new CountDownTimer(respawnTime, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timer =(Integer)(int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        if(timer < 31)
            timerText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        timerText.setText(timer.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timerText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        timerText.setText("UP");

    }
};
```

At this point I have respawnTime set to equal 360000 hoping for a 360 second countdown, but like I said it just immediately runs the onFinish. Simply changing the first parameter to a literal instead of a variable fixes everything but I need to use a variable here. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 @Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
```

to

```
 @Override
public void onTick(long respawnTime) {
```

use the variable you are sending in the `constructor` in `onTick()`.

**Edit**

Here is one of mine

```
private class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
{
    long duration, interval;
    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        duration = millisInFuture;
        interval = countDownInterval;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        secs = 10;
        Intent intent = new Intent(CalibrationTimeoutScreen.this, CalibrationTakeTempScreen.class);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);
        CalibrationTimeoutScreen.this.finish(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long duration) {
        cd.setText(String.valueOf(secs));           
        secs = secs - 1;            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I still seem to be having the problem. I changed what you suggested but it still just runs the onFinish immediately. Have any other suggestions? This one has me pretty stumped

Comment: Have you verified at that point, with breakpoints, that `respawnTime` is `360000 `?

Comment: I'm sorry, been a long night for me. I have edited with one of mine if that helps. Maybe multiply your `long` by 1000 instead of doing the casting you're doing

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, I've got to go out really quick but I will let you know as soon as I am able to try it

Comment: I implemented like you did in your example and it cleared everything right up. Still not sure why I was having my original problem but I have everything working now. Thanks a ton for the assistance. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You did not run `start()`. Simply add `.start()` after the last '}' or add a new line calling `countDown.start()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually call start() from another area in the code. Everything works fine until I try to pass the value as a variable instead of a literal